# Python literal IP get works, using data kwarg doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I guess I have a small problem dealing with requests. First things firs:

- I am using proxy servers on my Linux installation
- I am trying to get a response from a get from a simple input form

This is how it looks like:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by id" name="foo_id">
```

Now when I do something like this:

```py
import requests
foo_id = 42
resp = requests.get(f'{ip}?foo_id={foo_id}')
```

I get a 200 response, everything works fine.

But well, it doesn't look very nice, I should do it using a `data=` kwarg. So I changed my code to this:

```py
import requests
foo_id = '42'
resp = requests.get(ip, data={'foo_id': foo_id})
```

And it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<my_http_proxy_address>', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: <server_ip_address> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I even tried specifying a `proxies=` kwarg with a dict of proxies right from my `/etc/environment` - still it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `params` instead of `data`?

Comment: Gosh, that's so stupid of me. Yes, it works. Why does data appear in examples more often then?

Comment: IIRC `params` is for URL parameters, `data` is for body. As a rule of thumb, POST uses body parameters, and GET uses URL parameters. Most endpoints will not expect body in GET requests. You ran into an endpoint which probably is so surprised by lack of URL params (or less likely, presence of body params) that it breaks connection.

Comment: Okay, so clear now. Much thanks!